# Exporting multiple files with different filenames

Tags: python, import, export, filenames

Lets say I have `n` files in a directory with filenames: `file_1.txt, file_2.txt, file_3.txt .....file_n.txt`. I would like to import them into Python individually and then do some computation on them, and then store the results into `n` corresponding output files: `file_1_o.txt, file_2_o.txt, ....file_n_o.txt.`

I've figured out how to import multiple files:

```
import glob
import numpy as np

path = r'home\...\CurrentDirectory'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + '/*.txt')
for file in allFiles:
    # do something to file
    ...
    ...
    np.savetxt(file, ) ???
```

Not  quite sure how to append the `_o.txt` (or any string for that matter) after the filename so that the output file is `file_1_o.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the following snippet to build the output filename?

```
parts = in_filename.split(".")
out_filename = parts[0] + "_o." + parts[1]
```

where I assumed in_filename is of the form "file_1.txt".
Of course would probably be better to put `"_o."` (the suffix before the extension) in a variable so that you can change at will just in one place and have the possibility to change that suffix more easily.
In your case it means

```
import glob
import numpy as np

path = r'home\...\CurrentDirectory'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + '/*.txt')
for file in allFiles:
    # do something to file
    ...
    parts = file.split(".")
    out_filename = parts[0] + "_o." + parts[1]
    np.savetxt(out_filename, ) ???
```

but you need to be careful, since maybe before you pass `out_filename` to `np.savetxt` you need to build the full path so you might need to have something like
`np.savetxt(os.path.join(path, out_filename), )`
or something along those lines.
If you would like to combine the change in basically one line and define your "suffix in a variable" as I mentioned before you could have something like

```
hh = "_o." # variable suffix
..........
# inside your loop now
for file in allFiles:
    out_filename = hh.join(file.split("."))
```

which uses another way of doing the same thing by using join on the splitted list, as mentioned by @NathanAck in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

#put the path to the files here
filePath = "C:/stack/codes/"
theFiles = os.listdir(filePath)

for file in theFiles:
    #add path name before the file
    file = filePath + str(file)

    fileToRead = open(file, 'r')
    fileData = fileToRead.read()

    #DO WORK ON SPECIFIC FILE HERE
    #access the file through the fileData variable
    fileData = fileData + "\nAdd text or do some other operations"

    #change the file name to add _o
    fileVar = file.split(".")
    newFileName = "_o.".join(fileVar)

    #write the file with _o added from the modified data in fileVar
    fileToWrite = open(newFileName, 'w')
    fileToWrite.write(fileData)

    #close open files
    fileToWrite.close()
    fileToRead.close()
```